# Why the Git Bash shows nothing when i type command "git reflog"

Tags: git, git-reflog

When i type `git reflog` in the git bash, it show nothing. And when i select `show reflog` on the context manu of TortoiseGit, it says

> "error while loading reflog. libgit2 returned: unable to parse OID, contains invalid characters".

The other functions of git is good.
I have searched solutions of this problem for hours among Google and Bing. But it still can not be figured out. 
What should i try next to fix the problem or find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reflog for `HEAD` is a plain text file stored at `.git/logs/HEAD`.

You can check if this file exists, is accessible, and if you see something fishy in its content.

---

Each line should look like :

```
<sha1> <sha1> <author + unix timestamp + timezone> <1 line commit message>
```

From the error message : one of the `sha1` part must have been corrupted.

---

If the error is obvious enough (file truncated, obvious join of two lines ...) you can try to manually edit the file, and remove or fix the faulty lines.

The two `sha1` mean "the reference moved from this commit to this commit". So they are "linked" between lines : the second sha1 of line `n-1` is the first sha1 of line `n`, the first sha1 of line `n+1` is the second of line `n`.

Comment: Amazing! Just as what you said, all the text files at ```.git/logs/``` are corrupted. But whatever location i initialize a new local repository at, and do some commits. All the text files under ```.git/logs/```  generated by git will be corrupted, while other file under ```.git/``` is still normal. There are some invalid characters are always introduced into these files. I have tried reinstall git, but it does not work. How the file at ```.git/logs/``` modified by git?

Comment: Can you edit your question, and describe what kind of invalid content you see in your log files ?

Comment: It looks like ```2?程2爽梦:氚?C1匆J,5誚c嵉鏋sf49c7a18ac146012b644844f84f1c74b1b7f9275 0907b109fb13255c1fb88d3b649d72eae84904f7 RX-Deng <renxiongdeng@163.com> 1590503795 +0800 commit: this is another test commit``` BTW, I work with git in the language environment of Chinese.

Comment: Hi，i figure out this problem finally after i reinstall the git with version 2.18 in 32 bit while the version that i installed before is 2.26 in 64 bit. It is occured on the computer  that is in my company, so that i can not install other version except the two version i mentioned above. Thank you again.